# Google speech to text real-time in PHP

Tags: php, yii, grpc, speech-to-text, google-speech-api

I want to integrate Google speech to text real-time (microphone) in Yii2 project. As per Google document for real time speech to text integration we need gRPC, but in document we don't have any sample code for PHP like we do have for python, c#,node js, etc. Is it possible to integrate this in PHP/Yii application? If yes then do we have any sample code for PHP anywhere? Is there any document describes using gRPC for integration this?
Refered document from [here](https://cloud.google.com/speech-to-text/docs/streaming-recognize). Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why would you use PHP for a real time task? PHP is server side and is handled with a pull request. If you want to create a real time application I would suggest to use Node or some language which uses a push and pull model.

Comment: Thank you for replying, This one is a old project and in one module I want to integrate speech to text